# Permission to show badge number on PWA

Tags: android, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, badge

I have created a PWA for android and connected it with a service for Push Notifications. I want to show how many notifications I have by displaying a badge number on the app icon.

As I understand it, android displays this automatically. However when I install the PWA and go to my phones notifications settings, the badge permission is turned off on the PWA.

Does anybody know if I can set the permission on default or ask the user to give permission?